# Out of memory error in Kotlin when looping through a medium size data set

Tags: java, memory, kotlin, jvm, out-of-memory

I am running the below loop in Kotlin and is throwing an out of memory error. I am running this for reading the rows in a csv file. Size of "records" is 6422.

```
fun readCSVFile(filePath: String): List<String> {
    val reader = FileReader(filePath)
    val records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(reader)
    val rows = mutableListOf<String>()

    var output = ""
    records.forEach() {
        val size = it.size()
        for (i in 0 until it.size()-1) {
            output = output + it.get(i) + ","
        }
        output.dropLast(1)
        rows.add(output)
    }
    return rows
}
```

Below is the exception I get.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
at trivago.ti.tools.FileProcessor.readCSVFile(FileProcessor.kt:16)
at trivago.ti.tools.ComparatorMainKt.main(ComparatorMain.kt:25)
```

I have the same logic executing in Java but it works fine. Below is what I have in Java.

```
private static List<String> readCSVFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    Reader in = new FileReader(filePath);
    Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(in);
    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CSVRecord record : records) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < record.size(); i++)
            builder.append(record.get(i) + ",");
        builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
        rows.add(builder.toString());
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Why is Kotlin having a problem with this? Am I doing something wrong with the loop? Any help would be much appreciated as I'm a newbie to Kotlin.

Comment: What size is the CSV you are reading? What's the -Xmx value of your JVM (if you defined any yourself) ?

Comment: Sorry I edited the question. its 6422

Comment: In bytes? Also, did you define the -Xmx anywhere or is it default?

Comment: I guess the answers have solved the problem, so this is to solve another one: replace `i in 0 until it.size()-1` with `i in 0 until it.size()` or `i in 0..it.size()-1` because the code as it is loses the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` in your kotlin code as well. You are creating a log of `String` objects in heap. String is immutable and this code:

```
var output = ""
output = output + ","
```

is creating two objects in heap, although you have only reference to one of them. So the other one is eligible for GC to remove it. GC is "working" too hard in your case, that's why you get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

```
fun readCSVFile(filePath: String): List<String> {
    val reader = FileReader(filePath)
    val records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(reader)
    val rows = mutableListOf<String>()

    var output = StringBuilder("")
    records.forEach() {
        output = StringBuilder("")
        val size = it.size()
        for (i in 0 until it.size()-1) {
            output = output.append(it.get(i) + ",")
        }
        output.deleteCharAt(output.length - 1)
        rows.add(output.toString())
    }
    return rows
}
```

You code will also run a lot faster, as creating a new object is quite costly.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a bug in your code

```
records.forEach() {
    output = "" // clear output ;)
    ...
}
```

Compare it to your java code

```
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); // clear builder
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you try this ? I don't think this will help, as OP is getting ``GC overhead limit exceeded``, that means there are a lot of objects in heap

Comment: I agree that StringBuilder will help, but this will also help, because this is the cause of the GC having to run that many times.
rows.add(output) -> rows.add("row1");
rows.add(output) -> rows.add("row1row2");
rows.add(output) -> rows.add("row1row2row3");
rows.add(output) -> rows.add("row1row2row3...row6422");

Comment: this does not affect in any way how many time GC runs ``rows.add(output)``, the string just keeps getting bigger, OP's mistake

Comment: The string keeps getting bigger, running out of heap memory, will cause the GC to run. GC has been trying to free the memory but is pretty much unable to get any job done, as rows content cannot be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your Kotlin code:

1. You are using strings and string concatenation - which is costly operation. You should use StringBuilder as well.
2. You are setting `output = ""` outside of the foreach loop - for each iteration, you have all previous rows inside output